# invalidate params to create instance of NamedTuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want to define personal text for the action on create namepupled

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class User(NamedTuple):
    email: str
    username: str
```

and two solution of the make user function, the first has small code, but the error text is not enough readable for humans

```
def make_user(params: dict):
    try:
        user = User(**params)
    except TypeError as e:
        return None, e
    return user, None
```

result looks like:

```
params = {'email': '1@1.test'} 
make_user(params)

(None,
TypeError("__new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'"))
```

other solution is manual check fields before initial the instance:

```
def make_user_or_error(params: dict):
    user_required = User._fields ^ User._field_defaults.keys()
    required = [x for x in user_required if x not in params]
    if required:
        return None, f'You should provide values for the field(s): {",".join(required)}'
    return User(**params), None
```

and result is:

```
params = {'email': '1@1.test'} 
make_user_or_error(params)
(None, 'You should provide values for the field(s): username')
```

the question is: does exists the solution with minimal code as in the first, but with result as in the second

Answer (score 0):

You can go with a middle-ground solution by grabbing the name of the missing field from the error string and build the error message yourself.

The solution I present is very naive and handles one missing argument, I'm sure you will be able to generalize it.

```
from typing import NamedTuple
import re

missing_field_regex = re.compile(r"argument: '(.*)'")

class User(NamedTuple):
    email: str
    username: str


def make_user(params: dict):
    try:
        user = User(**params)
    except TypeError as e:
        return None, f'You should provide values for the field(s): {missing_field_regex.findall(str(e))[0]}'
    return user, None

params = {'email': '1@1.test'}
print(make_user(params))
# (None, 'You should provide values for the field(s): username')
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, and i upvote it, but regex do the code not enough readable for me.

Comment: @BearBrown Not enough readable to who? This solution outputs the exact output you wanted

Comment: I prefer not to use regex, if it does not need to use strongly. Because, if need to change logic it need more time for me, to read and update the regex. It is only my trouble.